# What is a shorter term for "grammatical correctness"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The only one I can think of is "pronunciation", but that one is more related to the way you say it rather than to the way you write it.

Comment: You can always just ask, “ Is this ***right?***”

Comment: @Jim Whether something is *right* is quite a different concept to *grammatical correctness*.

Comment: @Lawrence - Yes of course, but if someone is wanting to know if something is grammatically correct but doesn’t want to use the “normal words” for that then “right” is probably sufficient for their purposes.

Comment: @Jim If the context constrains the term sufficiently, that's fine.

Comment: @Lawrence - yeah it was just a comment.

Answer (score 9):

"The state or quality of being grammatical," or "grammatical correctness" is known as:

> grammaticality.

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/grammaticality)

And Mithrandir has provided the adjective form in [Mithrandir's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/378699/211575) above.

For example:

> Grammatical correctness is also known as **grammaticality.**
>
> Grammatical correctness as related to the way you write is also known as **grammaticality**.
>
> "In...linguistics...a **grammaticality** judgement...is based on whether the sentence is produced and interpreted in accordance with the rules and constraints of the relevant grammar" ("[Grammaticality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammaticality)," Wikipedia).
>
> "The **grammaticality** of a sentence is things that conform to the linguistic rules or syntactic rules (Fromkin and Rodman 1998:106) ("[The Grammaticality versus The Acceptability](https://arieandrasyah.wordpress.com/2009/08/01/the-grammaticality-versus-the-acceptability/)," Linguistik.)

Answer (score 6):

**grammatical** without 'correctness'?

> 1. of or relating to grammar:
>      *grammatical analysis.*
> 2. conforming to standard usage:
>      *grammatical speech.*
>      -[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/grammatical)

---

dictionary.com gives 'antigrammaticalness, noun' as a related word, so I assume that if you remove the 'anti' that gives 'grammaticalness', which should work as a noun.